# Using MongoDB and Java WITHOUT gradle, maven or an IDE

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB in java, without an IDE or additional tools. I have downloaded mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar, and put it in the same folder as my helloMongo.java file.

I then have tried to run it with:

```
javac -cp  "mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo.java
java -cp  "mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo
```

Only to get that it cannot find the main class.

Then I tried, assuming the main path had been lost in javas braindead implementation:

```
javac -cp  ".;mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo.java
java -cp  ".;mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo
```

still to no luck. Then I tried:

```
javac -cp  ".;/mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo.java
java -cp  ".;/mongo-java-driver.jar" helloMongo
```

And a hundred other variants, and still no luck.

Is an IDE and Gradle essentially required to use Mongo with Java?

```
package com.javatpoint.java.mongo.db;  
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;  
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;  
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;  
import org.bson.Document;  
public class JavaMongoDemo {  
public static void main(String[] args){  
try{  
//---------- Connecting DataBase -------------------------//  
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );  
//---------- Creating DataBase ---------------------------//  
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("javatpoint");  
//---------- Creating Collection -------------------------//  
MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection("employee");  
//---------- Creating Document ---------------------------//    
Document doc = new Document("name", "Peter John");  
doc.append("id",12);  
//----------- Inserting Data ------------------------------//  
table.insertOne(doc);  
}catch(Exception e){  
System.out.println(e);  
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: What does the `package` statement at the top of your Java file look like?  Post the Java file.

Answer (score -1):

If your package is `com.javatpoint.java.mongo.db`, then your class has to be in

```
./com/javatpoint/java/mongo/db
```

and assuming you leave the Mongo jar in the same directory as your source,
your `java` command must be

```
java -cp ./com/javatpoint/java/mongo/db/mongo-java-driver.jar com.javatpoint.java.mongo.db.helloMongo
```